# How would I pass environment into docker using bash?

Tags: bash, docker

The following works fine in docker:

```
docker run -i -t -rm -e a="hello world" b=world ubuntu /bin/bash
```

What it does is passes env var a with value "hello world" and env var b with value "world" into the docker container.

Thing is, I need to generate that from script.

It is super easy to get this working for env vars without space:

```
ENV_VARS='-e a=helloworld b=world'
docker run -i -t -rm $ENV_VARS ubuntu /bin/bash
```

However, once there is a space in the env var I am hosed:

```
ENV_VARS='-e a="hello world" b=world'
docker run -i -t -rm $ENV_VARS ubuntu /bin/bash

Unable to find image 'world"' (tag: latest) locally
2014/01/15 16:28:40 Invalid repository name (world"), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed
```

How can I get the above example to work? I also tried arrays but can not get them to work.

Comment: Does docker clear the environment?  Can you just export the desired variables?

Comment: Yeah you must be explicit about what env vars you allow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Bash arrays are designed to solve exactly this sort of problem*

First step is to declare the array:

```
docker_env=(-e "a=hello world" "b=world")
```

Which lets you programmatically populate more environment variables, for example:

```
docker_env+=("c=foo bar")
```

Finally run it:

```
docker run -i -t -rm "${docker_env[@]}" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: accepting this, ended up doing something along these lines: https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker/commit/4b563ee8d6c5c48570566bd2e358d64581cedb54 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about instead:

```
a='hello world'
b='some more'
docker run -i -t -rm -e a -e b ...
```

Does this do what you need in an eaiser way?

Comment: I can't really do that cause I need to work for a dynamic set of env vars

Answer (score 1):

```
eval docker run -i -t -rm "$ENV_VARS" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: aha, is eval considered evil or is it a sane use here?

Comment: Some people consider it always evil to use eval.  If you are constructing the string carefully, it is probably safe.  Make sure there are no semi-colons.  Probably best to enusre the string only contains [a-z 0-9].  Hmmm, no, it's not safe.  eval is always evil!

Comment: yeah ... I need semicolumn support, otherwise big trouble

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem of the space containing variables passed to docker environment using option --env-file. In the env file the line separated variable definitions are expected. Following example illustrates the pattern.

```
DOCKER_ENV=$(mktemp run-docker-env.XXXXXXX)
echo Using env file: $DOCKER_ENV
echo VAR1=$VARZZZ > $DOCKER_ENV
echo VAR2=value >> $DOCKER_ENV
echo VAR_WITH_SPACE=variable value with space >> $DOCKER_ENV

docker run --env-file=${DOCKER_ENV} image:latest

rm $DOCKER_ENV
```